# Removing "tag" from rewrite rule that looks like this:

Tags: tags, url-rewriting, rule

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1&tag=true&from=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1&tag=true [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/page/(.+)/?$ search.php?search=$1&tag=true&page=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The above rules seem to rewrite a dynamic url into a seo friendly url.

the end result looks like this `http://www.example.com/tag/word`

I would like it to look like this `http://www.example.com/word`

Can anyone help me to change the existing rewrite rule correctly in order not to generate a "tag" folder?

Answer (score 0):

The rules are not rewriting to seo friendly urls. You begin with the sep friendly url like what you have in your end results. Internally, those rules rewrite it to the actual url that will do the work. So, I'm not sure if you want a rule to process example.com/word instead of example.com/tag/word. If that's the case, just remove the "tag" from the beginning of the RewriteRules